# Penalty Matrix in P-Splines with correlated data

Tags: time-series, regularization, splines

Good evening,

I'm having some trouble understanding how the penalty matrix in penalized splines is set up if the error term has a stationary process.

Say I have $y=X\beta+ \epsilon$ with $\epsilon \sim AR(1)$ and $cov(\epsilon)=R$ which is a variance-covariance matrix. Then the minimization of the penalized spline regression with a stationary process has the following solution,
$$\hat{\beta}=(X^T R^{-1}X+ \lambda D)^{-1} X^TR^{-1}y$$

Where $D$ is the penalty matrix, $X$ is a design matrix, $\lambda$ is the penalty term and $y$ is the response values and $\beta$ are the estimated parameter values. So now my question is what does the penalty matrix $D$ appear as with correlated values?

As a short example, if we consider a univariate process with a linear spline basis $k=2$ knots, $n=10$, and $AR(1)$ stationary process. $X$ the design matrix would be $10$ by $5$, $R$ the variance-covariance matrix is square $10$ by $10$, $y$ is $10$ by $1$ and $D$ would be a square $5$ by $5$ matrix.

Now the first 4 columns of $X$ would represent the terms associated with the intercept, linear basis, and two knots basis. The last column would be associated for the $\phi_1$ parameter in the $AR(1)$ process. This is important as it also defines the setup for the penalty matrix $D$ such that the first 2 rows and columns are going to be 0, then most of the values in rows 3/4 and columns 3/4 depend on the knot locations however I am unsure what the remaining values in 5th row and 5th column should be.

From a visual perspective here's what a penalty matrix may appear as where I am unsure how the values(labeled as ?'s) for the 5th row and 5th column be obtained from the $AR(1)$ process. Any help in understanding this would be greatly appreciated.

[image]